# How to create a elementor template gallery with own templates

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have been trying to figure out and searching everywhere to make a custom template gallery like `happy adons` or `essential-addons` or simialr plugin. They place an icon just beside the elementor folder icon and clicking on their icon they show their own template library right inside the elementor modal. How to do this feature? Thanks

[image]

[image]